# How to use @unchecked for an Option in a higher order function

Tags: scala

Say I have the following:

```
case class A(i: Int, flag: Option[Boolean])

val as = Seq(A(2, Some(true)), A(3, Some(false)))

val x = as.filter {
    case A(_, Some(flag)) => flag
}
```

Please Note. I am asking purely from the syntactical point of view and have tried to make the example as simple as possible to show this. In my scenario I am 100% certain that my option will be a Some.

So the question is - what would be the syntax for @unchecked in the above example?

Comment: There is a reason why the warning is there. Why you want to ignore it? How can you be sure that there would never be an **None**.

Comment: Syntactically speaking, try `as.filter((_: A @unchecked) match { case A(_, Some(flag)) => flag })`

Comment: How 'bout: `as.filter(_.flag.get)`

Comment: I just seen your edit when you said in your real code you are 100% sure you have a **Some**. Then, let me tell you that you have a bigger problem, because your types are lying. Care to share something more close to your real code? Because then you are either using an useless type or your assumption is wrong. If it is the former, there may be ways to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of suppressing the warning consider

```
as.filter(_.flag.contains(true))
```